# Why $\|a+b\|^2 = \|a\|^2 + \|b\|^2 + 2\langle a,b \rangle$?

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality, normed-spaces, inner-products

This might be a simple and even stupid question. Why does the following equation hold true? 
\begin{align}
\|a+b\|^2 = \|a\|^2 + \|b\|^2 + 2\langle a,b \rangle
\end{align}
where the norm can be induced naturally by the inner product.

From the triangle inequality we have
\begin{align}
\|a+b\| \le \|a\| + \|b\|
\end{align}
Then we take square at both sides
\begin{align}
\|a+b\|^2 \le \|a\|^2 + \|b\|^2 + 2\|a\|\|b\| = \|a\|^2 + \|b\|^2 + 2 \sqrt{\langle a,a \rangle \langle b,b \rangle}
\end{align}
It seems close to the proof but I am not able to continue. Can you please show me the equation at first for Euclidean space and then for all inner product spaces?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that

\begin{align}
\|a+b\|^2 = \langle a+b, a+b\rangle = \|a\|^2+\|b\|^2+2\langle a,b\rangle
\end{align}

Note that we require $\langle a, b \rangle = \langle b, a \rangle$ for this to hold.

Remark:

From your working, you are very close to a proof of Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

Comment: Thank you very much. I already recognized the equation and saw the approach to Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. One additional question, under what condition can we draw a conclusion that $\|a-b\|^2 \le \|a\|^2 + \|b\|^2$?

Comment: expanding LHS, we get $\|a\|^2-2\langle a,b \rangle +\|b\|^2$.

Comment: Thank you! While $\|a \pm b\|^2 \lesssim \|a\| ^2+ \|b\|^2$ is always true, because $\|a \pm b\|^2 = \|a\|^2 + \|b\|^2 \pm 2 \langle a,b \rangle \le \|a\|^2 + \|b\|^2 + 2\|a\|\|b\| \le 2 (\|a\| ^2+ \|b\|^2)$. Is that correct?

Comment: It is not always true, we end up with the condition that $\pm \langle a, b \rangle \le 0$.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** You're after an equality. In order to prove it, expand $\|a+b\|^2=\langle a+b,a+b\rangle$.

Comment: Thank you for your hint. I already recognize the equation. One additional question, under what condition can we draw a conclusion that $\|a-b\|^2 \le \|a\|^2 + \|b\|^2$?

Comment: @AnalysisNewbie It is always true.

Comment: But $\|a+b\|^2 \le \|a\|^2 + \|b\|^2$ seems not always true if $\langle a,b \rangle < 0$. Then if we take $b = -b$, the inequality aforementioned is not true as well. Am I right?

Comment: @AnalysisNewbie Sorry. My mistake. I was thinking about $\|a-b\|\leqslant\|a\|+\|b\|$. The inequality that you mentioned holds if and only if $\langle a,b\rangle\geqslant0$.

Comment: Thank you! While $\|a \pm b\|^2 \lesssim \|a\| ^2+ \|b\|^2$ is always true, because $\|a \pm b\|^2 = \|a\|^2 + \|b\|^2 \pm 2 \langle a,b \rangle \le \|a\|^2 + \|b\|^2 + 2\|a\|\|b\| \le 2 (\|a\| ^2+ \|b\|^2)$. Is that correct?

Answer (score 2):

$$\|a + b\| = \langle a + b, a + b\rangle.$$
Now distribute.  Note that if the inner product space is complex you get $2\Re(\langle a, b \rangle)$ forthe middle term.